# How to batch whiten photos of text files (using Bimp or other method)

Tags: gimp

When I take photos of text pages with my phone, all the white space are quite grey. I can whiten the page using Gimp by going to menu item "Colors", selecting "Levels" to go to the "Adjust Color Levels" and adjusting the input level pointer for white.

How can this be done in a batch mode for multiple files?

I installed the Bimp plugin. I searched through all the "Other GIMP procedures" in the Bimp dialog box but could not find anything that appears to do what is possible with the "Adjust Color Levels" dialog box.

Is this possible to be done using the Bimp plugin?

If not, is this possible using Gimp batch mode and can someone point me to batch code that I could use to get started with doing this?

Comment: In practice when you take a picture you phone computes the exposure to make is gray on average, so when your picture is a page which is mostly white like printed text, it is underexposed. If you phone camera allow it, tell if to overexpose by one or two EV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BIMP on a folder full of images. When you click on Add Images, select the Add Folders option. Don't forget to also specify the Ouput folder where you want the edited images to be saved.

[image]

Then click the +Add button in the manipulation set and choose Colour Correction, and set it up as shown below. Obviously the actual settings you choose for the Colour Correction will depend on the originals. Here I chose to *Convert to Greyscale*, and increased the *Contrast* slider. You may have to experiment to get the best result for your images.

[image]

When you hit the Apply button, BIMP will apply the edit you set up to all the images in the Input folder, and save them in the Output folder

Here's the example input file I used (left), and the output (right).

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.